# How to make SSH's `ControlPath` distinguish between IPv4 and IPv6?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I'm using

```
ControlMaster   auto
ControlPath     ~/.ssh/tmp/%l_%r@%h:%p
```

in my `~/.ssh/config` to open multiple sessions using the same connection when accessing a host via SSH.

That works fine for most use cases, but doesn't allow me to connect to the same hostname via IPv4 and IPv6 at the same time; all additional connections use the control socket created by the first connection because the `ControlPath` doesn't allow to distinguish between IPv4 and IPv6 connections.

Is there a way to have separate control sockets for IPv4 and IPv6 connections (perhaps by finding a way to use the remote IP rather then the remote hostname in the socket path)?

---

**EDIT #1**

I just remembered the `Match` option available in `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` files and tried:

```
Match AddressFamily inet
    ControlPath     ~/.ssh/tmp/%l_%r@%h:%p.inet

Match AddressFamily inet6
    ControlPath     ~/.ssh/tmp/%l_%r@%h:%p.inet6
```

Unfortunately, that fails with "*Unsupported Match attribute AddressFamily*" when I try to connect to any host, so I'm back to square one…

Comment: When you're running ssh to connect to a host, and there's a choice of using ipv4 or ipv6, how are you currently controlling which is used? ie, ignoring the question of control masters, if you wanted to open two sessions to the same host using different protocols, how are you doing it?

Comment: @Kenster I normally just `ssh host` (letting the OS and DNS resolver decide which protocol to use). Recently my IPv6 tunnel has been having issues with packet loss, so when that happens, I `ssh -4 host` to continue working — which currently doesn't work because it uses the existing control socket, so I have to kill the IPv6 connection first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>I've split my answer into two separate answers so you can up/downvote the "wrapper" and "patch" approaches separately.</sup>

#### Solution 1: Write a wrapper function

```
ssh ()
{
    controlpath=""
    for argument in $@
    do
        if [[ "$argument" = "-"*"4"* ]]
        then
            controlpath="~/.ssh/tmp/%l_%r@%h:%p.inet"
        fi
        if [[ "$argument" = "-"*"6"* ]]
        then
            controlpath="~/.ssh/tmp/%l_%r@%h:%p.inet6"
        fi
    done

    if [ -n "$controlpath" ]
    then
        /usr/bin/ssh -o "ControlPath=$controlpath" $@
    else
        /usr/bin/ssh $@
    fi
}
```

This wrapper function will instruct `ssh` to create separate control sockets for `ssh host`, `ssh -4 host`, and `ssh -6 host`.
It might not parse something like `ssh -464466 host` correctly (even though that's technically allowed), but it should be the easiest workaround for simple scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

This is not typical use case so there is no direct way of doing so. But, you can workaround this using user configuration file as such, if you don't require too many remote hosts:

```
Host hostname-4
    Hostname hostname
    AddressFamily inet
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/master4-%l%h%p%r
Host hostname-6
    Hostname hostname
    AddressFamily inet6
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/master6-%l%h%p%r
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't scale very well and requires me to remember to edit my config file whenever I want to connect to a new host…

Comment: @n-st - can you not take the above and make the Host's `*-4` and `*-6`, change the `Hostname ...` to `Hostname %h`?

Comment: This wouldn't work, because `%h` would be full `hostname-4`. But nice idea. As a workaround, you can set up some script to generate this config on-the-fly. But it is still not much elegant.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>I've split my answer into two separate answers so you can up/downvote the "wrapper" and "patch" approaches separately.</sup>

#### Solution 2: *Use the source, Luke!*

Like I mentioned in the update to my answer, OpenSSH doesn't support `Match AddressFamily` — *yet*.
It's fairly easy to add a corresponding clause to the `Match` parsing in [readconf.c](https://anongit.mindrot.org/openssh.git/tree/readconf.c?id=df56a8035d429b2184ee94aaa7e580c1ff67f73a#n554). My proof-of-concept patch worked, but involved a bunch of hardcoded strings, so it certainly needs some more work before I can submit it to the OpenSSH maintainers for consideration.

<sub>It might also be worth a look if we can't just add another placeholder (like `%a`) for `ControlPath` definitions that would evaluate to `any`, `inet` or `inet6`, depending on the address family used.

That will however cause issues depending on the order in which the `AddressFamily` and `ControlPath` options are evaluated and stored, so it might require some fairly extensive changes to work.

The same problem applies to my original idea of expanding the placeholder to the actual address family used for the connection: The address family depends on a `gethostbyname()` call that isn't even made when a suitable control socket exists.</sub>